# Polyurethane coating drying splotchy, despite stain taking to the wood just fine

Tags: woodworking, stain, finishing, polyurethane

## The issue:

[image]

---

I've been refinishing an old table I've had sitting around for years that was in terrible shape, stain-wise. Yesterday I sanded off the old stain down to 220, wiped up the dust with a damp rag, then stained with Varathane Ultimate (oil based) using a lint-free cloth. I left it overnight.

As of this morning, it looked beautiful, no flaws, was ready for clear coat. [image]

I applied some varathane oil based poly earlier (again, with a rag, after thinning it 50-50 with mineral spirits). I started with the underside to make sure it would take properly, let it dry a few hours, and no issue.

Then I moved to the top. Everything looked good, checked on it every 30 minutes or so and no issue, then came back a few hours later and suddenly, these splotches showed up!

The splotches have no sheen to them, so I assumed it just meant the poly for some reason didnt coat there. But after trying a second coat of poly just now, figuring it would fill in those spots, they didn't go away and now (I assume) are sealed under a coat of poly

What went wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: "stained with Varathane Ultimate (oil based)"- AFAIK Varathane doesn't make a stain called "Ultimate". There is the "Classic" line of wood stains, and there is the "Fast Dry", which is marked "Premium". Please edit your question with the **exact** stain you used, including the color.